# How to instantiate a view controller programatically, without storyboard

Tags: swift, contactpicker

Is there a way to instantiate a view controller programatically without using storyboard identifier. I want to push CNContactPickerController into my root view controller .

```
let controller = CNContactPickerViewController()
controller.delegate = self
navigationController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

i did this but in contactPicker (delegate) i push a VC from storyboard where i save what info i want from that specific contact.
The problem: when i pop the last view controller i want to go on the CNConctactPickerControllerView but i go on the first view controller
i tried with dismiss but nothing happens..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with doing this is that **NONE** of the UI for your view controller is created. What you are doing is simply instantiating an instance of the class. None of the corresponding UI is created, also your `IBOutlet`s will be nil.

You have 2 options, either you use Interface builder and instantiate from the Nib or Storyboard, or you create **ALL** your UI manually in code.

For the sake of resuability you could create a static method on `CNContactPickerViewController` to handle the storyboard instantiation for you. See the following:

```
class CBContactPickerViewController: UIViewController {

    static func fromStoryboard() -> CNContactPickerViewController {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "foobar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "CNContactPickerViewController") as! CNContactPickerViewController
    }
}
```

You can then utilise this as follows:

```
self.present(viewController: CNContactPickerViewController.fromStoryboard(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```